# my primary key is used as foreign key in the table of my db

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, primary-key

I have a scenario as seen below "
record1:

```
ID            2
MenuName      Our Team
MenuIcon      fa-globe
ParentID      1
MenuURL       /about/ourteam
MenuPosition  1
record2:
ID            1
MenuName      About
MenuIcon      fa-globe
ParentID      0
MenuURL       /about
MenuPosition  1
```

"

And follows same sequence for all the menu.
The problem is there are some that must not have a submenu I want to do a method that check if that parent menu name is equal to another set of names called products in another table then no sub menu should be attached.

here is my code

```
    <?php foreach($menus as $menu):?>

     <?php 
     if ($menu->name == $product->name){

     echo 'cannot attach sub-menu on product';

     }
     else {
     //call the add and detached submenu function
     }
    ?>
```

Am using codeigniter.
I have passed the record on the controller to a variable called `$menus`

using eloquent db function. `$menus = MenuModel::all();`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CI try:

`$menues = $this->db->get('menus')->result()`

Comment: The result of the above is same